# Jetpack compose from expanded bottomsheet to fullscreen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

Want to achieve something like in gif below using Jetpack Compose, does anyone know best soulution for this, used bottom sheet, but couldnt convert it to fullscreen https://miro.medium.com/max/304/1*lZTBcYUYb8eB65x_7bWbjw.gif

Comment: Kindly provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded: ModalBottomSheetValue
```

You have Expanded, HalfExpanded, Hidden.

If you choose Expanded: "The bottom sheet is visible at full height."

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ModalBottomSheetValue#summary)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, that is exactly what I was searching for)

Comment: Great, please accept the answer in that case, so others know it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Now in M3 jetpack compose if you turn this option to true it will handle Hiding and Expanding automatically

```
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = true)
```

Comment: No it doesn't. When I have a ModalBottomSheet, it does not automatically expand when you drag up the handle. It will keep its size and not further go up.